# Software center does not load after upgrade and terminal does not allow me to enter password

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, apt, software-center

I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and now software center does not work and when I open Dash  it cannot access any applications.

When I tried some of the solutions posted the terminal asks me the sudo password for but does take any input from the keyboard.

How can I enter my password or solve these problems?

Comment: If you click ctrl+alt+f1 will it change to a terminal? (press ctrl+alt+f7 to go back to graphical).

Comment: Insufficient data to answer the question. What errors does the Software Center return? What solutions did you try? And what was the specific result of each? Terminal password input is hidden, so do we really know that they system is somehow not accepting just the password?

Comment: Marking this as **too localized** due to insufficient data and long period of inactivity.